# AE importing my 60fps (59.94) video as 29.97fps

Tags: frame-rate, after-effects

I've never had this issue. And I can't seem to find any reference to it either. **I have some footage shot at 60fps** on my camera (I've even corroborated that it has been shot at 60fps by checking the EXIF data). However, **when I import this footage into AE (CS6) it's placing it as a 29.97 frame-rate**. I can't get it to respect the 60 fps. And I need it to do so because I'm looking to slow the footage down by, afterwards, lowering the frame-rate.

What is going on? Anybody out there knows?

Thanks!

Comment: what video format is it?

Comment: Hi, Wagner. It's in MOV.

Comment: @WagnerPatriota it's in MOV 60i.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is your footage is *not true 60p*. It being 60i, AE will handle it **as full frames in a 29.97 comp**.

Try playing around with the conformed framerate by right clicking the footage and selecting `Interpret->Main`.
Also try separating the fields in the same dialog under `Fields and Pulldown`.